# Docker cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing

Tags: php, docker

My `Dockerfile` builds the PHP container seemingly without errors and all added PHP extensions are loaded `Additional .ini files parsed`. But when looking at the output during the build I see this:

```
#10 71.97 Build process completed successfully
#10 71.97 Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so'
#10 71.98 install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-3.2.0
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "extension=imagick.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "extension=imagick.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "extension=imagick.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "extension=memcached.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so" to php.ini
#10 71.98 cannot open php.ini "/usr/local/etc/php" for writing
#10 71.98 You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so" to php.ini
#10 72.05 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#10 72.32 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#10 72.54 (1/1) Installing .docker-php-ext-enable-deps (20230202.070642)
#10 72.55 OK: 459 MiB in 136 packages
#10 72.84 (1/1) Purging .docker-php-ext-enable-deps (20230202.070642)
#10 72.84 OK: 459 MiB in 135 packages
```

Should I just ignore it or is there some way to fix it?

The  `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

RUN pear config-set php_ini "$PHP_INI_DIR"

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS libzip-dev zlib-dev gmp-dev libmemcached-dev linux-headers imagemagick-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd gmp pdo_mysql opcache zip

# I have tried adding this and still I get the same error
# php.ini will in this case be owned by `root` in the container
# If I add the user "docker" and let that user own the file I get the same error
RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN pecl install imagick redis memcached xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick redis memcached xdebug

COPY ./xdebug/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN addgroup -g 1000 docker && adduser -D -u 1000 -G docker -s /bin/sh docker

USER docker
```

Relevant screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Next line clearly states: `You should add "extension=imagick.so" to php.ini`, so either do it manually or change permissions for `php.ini` to make it automatic (e.g. `chmod 0666 php.ini`)

Comment: @Justinas Regarding changing the permissions of the file. Since the root in the container owns the file, shouldn't it work? Also the extensions already works, so why should it bee added to th php.ini?

Comment: Extensions only works if it's added in php.ini

Comment: @Justinas as you see in `Additional .ini files parsed` the extensions are loaded and parsed.

Comment: But are there added additional extensions _in that file_, e.g. `imagick`? There must be `extension=imagick.so` inside extensions list _and_ in php info there must be information about that extension.